# Sumifs Ratio in PowerPivot

Tags: filter, dax, powerpivot, sumifs

I have a table in Excel, utilizing Power Pivot that I then display/filter using a Pivot Table. Within my dataset, calculating a ratio within Power Pivot that "sums" correctly in the pivot table based on slicers is fine - this utilizes a SUMX(Cost)/SUMX(Total) and everything works fine. By sums correctly, I mean if I further break down the data set based on Region/State/Product/Employee, all those Rows sum up correctly for the ratio percentage.

The dataset is filtered based on a single month or range of months. The result of this works fine for either the single month or range of Months. What I'm trying to do is within my Pivot Table, show a current month ratio AND a year to date ratio. I've tried messing around with equations I've found online, but nothing seems to work. This includes the following attempts:

=CALCULATE([Cost],[ProductID]="224594")/CALCULATE([Total],[ProductID]="224594")

=SUMX (FILTER(ALL('TableName'),PATHCONTAINS ('TableName'[ProductID], EARLIER('TableName'[ProductID]))),'TableName'[Cost]) / SUMX(FILTER(ALL('TableName'),PATHCONTAINS('TableName'[ProductID], EARLIER ('TableName'[ProductID]))),'TableName'[Total])

I need the "sumifs" to sum the cost for Product A for all months divided by the sum of total for Product A for all months. I do not want to hard code in the the Product ID into the equation, but simply sum all previous records for that product, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Any suggestions?

[Sample Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HIy9.png)

Comment: Your expected results table lists Products 1, 2, 3 and 4, though I can't see these in the source data, only 6-digit Product IDs. Some realistic expected results would be welcome.

Comment: I was using those equations as a "measure" instead of calculating in a new column. Placing the equation into a column worked as intended. At that point, I just used sumifs in the underlying excel table and then used the measure and I got what I needed. I did this in 2 columns for a "cost" & "total", and then used the measure to divide cost/total.

=CALCULATE(sumx(append1,Append1[detail_Dir]),FILTER(Append1,Append1[Period Ending]<=EARLIER(Append1[Period Ending])),FILTER(Append1,Append1[Employee Number]=EARLIER(Append1[Employee Number])),FILTER(Append1,Append1[detail_GroupColumn]="Periods"))

Answer (score 0):

I used the calculate and filter functions in a column instead of trying to use them in a measure, which fixed the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).